# Loading a .user.ini PHP conf file using the PHP 5.4 internal server?

Tags: php

How do you load a `.user.ini` PHP configuration file when using the built in web server?

My setup is like this:

```
site
│   include.php
│
├───bin
│       router.php
│       server.bat
│
└───public
        .user.ini
        index.php
```

The document root is `public`, and `bin\router.php` routes to `public\index.php` if the file does not exist.

I did a `phpinfo()`, to verify that the `.user.ini` was not being loaded. The setting I am trying to change is `error_log`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Petah, I've just twigged what the issue is from your comment.  The built-in webserver was only introduced in 5.4

> This web server is designed for developmental purposes only, and should not be used in production.

It acts as a webserver listening on the specified socket.  The [.user.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) states that:

> These files are processed ***only*** by the CGI/FastCGI SAPI. This functionality obsoletes the PECL htscanner extension. If you are using Apache, use .htaccess files for the same effect.

In other words you can't use .user.ini files with the built-in webserver or with Apache/mod_php, etc.  You have to use a custom php.ini.  The safest way to do this is to clone the default php.ini (or php_value/flag directives with Apache/mod_php) and then add the lines you want for development.  Of course you could always just add an ini_set command in you script(s) startup as well.

Comment: I understand your points. But its a shame, as I can't use the system php.ini file (with the OS specific stuff), and then supplement a few options per site.

Answer (score 1):

While not an exact answer to my question, I found a solution to my problem.

In the `server.bat` file I was running the php server using

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:3000 -t public bin/router.php
```

By changing it to:

```
php -c public/.user.ini -S 0.0.0.0:3000 -t public bin/router.php
```

Achieved the same effect.

Comment: Petah, I guess that this is a Windows-specific Q&A.  All the -c option does is to force the path of the **php.ini**.  This is *not* the same as the 5.3+ `.user.ini` which supplements the main **php.ini**.

Comment: Not really Windows specific, I'm just on Windows this second. But I do agree the solution is not perfect so I'm still looking for an answer.

Comment: One way to do it would be to use `<(cat file1.ini file2.ini)` to combine settings. But it is not very easily to implement to match how PHP looks for ini files in CLI method. You have to take into account `PHPRC` variable as well.