# How to correctly use `.user.ini`-file in PHP?

Tags: php, settings, ini

In my working directory I have two files: `index.php` and `.user.ini`:

`.user.ini`:

```
display_errors=on

; http://be2.php.net/manual/en/filter.configuration.php#ini.filter.default
;filter.default = "full_special_chars"
```

`index.php`:

```
<?php
//ini_set("display_errors", "on");

// Use `.user.ini` file:
// http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php
echo "Setting for 'user_ini.filename': " . ini_get("user_ini.filename");
echo "\n\n";


// It takes up to five minutes, until `.user.ini` is re-read:
echo "Setting for 'user_ini.cache_ttl': " . ini_get("user_ini.cache_ttl");
echo "\n\n";

// http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php
echo "Setting for 'display_errors': " . ini_get("display_errors");
echo "\n\n";
echo "Setting for 'filter.default': " . ini_get("filter.default");
echo "\n\n";

// php -S localhost:8000
// http://localhost:8000/
```

Using the above `.user.ini`-file (in my working directory) I expect the `"Setting for 'display_errors': "` having a value of `on` or `1`, but it's empty.

How to correctly change settings using the `.user.ini`-file?

running `php --ini` results in

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
```

which does not contain my `.user.ini`-file.

Explicitly adding the `.user.ini`-file works:

```
php --php-ini .user.ini index.php
```

but I'd like it to be automatically read when running the script from a given folder.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) it says:

> These files are processed only by the CGI/FastCGI SAPI

and

> If you are using Apache, use `.htaccess` files for the same effect.

So if you run PHP as an Apache module, from the commandline, or using the builtin-Server, the `.user.ini`-files are not processed.

To find out your Server API, simply generate a PHP script with the following content and call it in your webbrowser:

```
<? phpinfo();
```

Comment: Is there a PHP-function that returns the Server-API?

Comment: @Edward You can use [`php_sapi_name()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php).

Comment: @CMCDragonkai yes, but only if your local server is configured as FastCGI module. You can recognize it by checking phpinfo(); in row `Server API`.

Comment: @Arxeiss My tests showed that it doesn't work for `php -S`.

Comment: Somehow I skimmed the docs and missed this multiple times when trying to use .user.ini with `php -S`. Thanks for making it obvious for me. Additionally, I found it also does not use /etc/php-cli.ini. After checking `php_sapi_name()`, I was successful with /etc/php-cli-server.ini

Answer (score 4):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Check `user_ini.filename` in your main `php.ini` to make sure it's not blank and it is indeed parsed. If its value is blank then PHP doesn't scan at all.

Also see the value of `user_ini.cache_ttl`

Please take a look at

[php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php)

Also check this question out
[Loading a .user.ini PHP conf file using the PHP 5.4 internal server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027886/loading-a-user-ini-php-conf-file-using-the-php-5-4-internal-server)

Comment: Thats what the `index.php` already does. The output is: `Setting for 'user_ini.filename': .user.ini` and  `Setting for 'user_ini.cache_ttl': 300`. So at least after five minutes the correct settings should be returned by the `index.php` - but they aren't,...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `.htaccess` for PHP config, you can create `.user.ini` file and put your settings there.

(without any indent or space)

For example my `.user.ini` config is:

```
max_execution_time=600
upload_max_filesize=200M
post_max_size=200M
memory_limit=256M
```

Comment: Are you sure spaces will not work? Also please note there is a space in your .user.ini (see first line max_execution_time =600)