# When php.ini or .user.ini file is loaded on the server?

Tags: php, server, cgi

I am new to the world of web and want to know that when server default **php.ini** file, custom **php.ini(that we created manually and added into per directory)** file, **.user.ini** file is loaded/read by the server ?

According to my concept these files are loaded/read on each request or loaded/read on each process at the cgi.

Can anyone tell in easy words ?

Comment: Are you using Apache? If you are, use `.htaccess` for the same effect. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179160/how-to-correctly-use-user-ini-file-in-php

Comment: My question was when these files are loaded/read by the server, my question was not as you answered bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the documentation, the default php.ini is loaded, when php is started. You can place your custom user.ini in the same location. Php is looking in default directories for all *.ini-files for including. You have to restart php whenever you apply changes to the configuration.

FYI, [manual - the configuration file](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)